# Groovy byte literal puzzle

Tags: java, groovy

How to specify an inline byte literal with groovy? The concrete problem is the need to specify a byte argument to an interface declared as follow:

```
public @interface Version {
    byte value();
}
```

Which only allow the use of inline values.

Comment: The same issue exists for `short`

Comment: The ugly thing is that it does not even allow the use of byte const.